# Inconsistent id generated with an sql sequence

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a Trace class, and I need to save its instances in an Oracle DB.

I choose to generate its id with a sequence, like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRACES")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TraceGen", sequenceName = "SEQ_TRACE_ID")
public class Trace {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TraceGen")
    @Column(name = "TRACE_ID")
    int traceId;
    @Column(name = "DEAL_ID")
    String dealId;
    // etc.

    public Trace(int traceId, String dealId, String nttId, Long runId, String step, String type, String trace, Date date) {
        super();
        this.traceId = traceId;
        this.dealId = dealId;
        this.nttId = nttId;
        this.runId = runId;
        this.step = step;
        this.type = type;
        this.trace = trace;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Somewhere else in the code, I create my Trace instances and save them like this :

```
traceDAO.setTrace(new Trace(0, deal.getId(), ntt.getId(), run.getRunId(), "AAA", type, message, new Date()));
```

The TraceDao class :

```
@Repository("traceDAO")
@Transactional("cvaTxManager")
public class TraceDAO implements TraceAccess {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cvaSessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;

    @Override
    public void setTrace(Trace trace) throws HibernateException {
        if (session == null) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(trace);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

The sequence was created with :

`CREATE SEQUENCE  SEQ_TRACE_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;`

The problem :

`select SEQ_TRACE_ID.nextval from dual` returns `1035`.

However, when I want to manually insert a new line in the `TRACES` table with `insert into TRACES (TRACE_ID, RUN_ID, NTT_ID, DEAL_ID, STEP, TYPE, TRACE, DATE_INSERT) VALUES (seq_acc_trace_id.nextval, 22, '', '', '', '', '', '')`, I get this error :

`SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (PRD.PK_TRACE_ID) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.`

What can I do ?

Also, is it normal that in the `TRACES` table, I have traces with an `id > SEQ_TRACE_ID.nextval` ?

Comment: Do you really have to use an increasing sequence number?

Comment: `select SEQ_TRACE_ID.nextval from dual returns 1035` does this happens always.?

Comment: @fge : well, I am considering using triggers to increase the id instead.

Comment: @eatSleepCode: there hasn't been any insert since the problem, so the select currently returns the same value.

Comment: This is not what I meant; I meant to ask whether you really needed the id to start at 1 and increase instead of, for instance, generate a random ID

Comment: no, it should always return next value.

Comment: @eatSleepCode: my bad, you were right, it now returns 1059

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can imagine of two issues that can lead to this issue.

1. Your sequence is also used by an other entity to generate its id´s and you have side effects with this of
2. your DBMS has a prefetch_size set on the sequence. Instead of using sequence one after the other it reserves a complete frame of (e.g.) 50 values and uses only 1. That means 49 values of your sequence are gone.
   What DBMS do you use?

EDIT: Sorry, i saw ORA-??? => you use Oracle. There you have this prefetch_size (on oracle called 'cache') see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm -> cache

Comment: I don't think it's a cache problem, since the sequence was created using NOCACHE

Comment: do you create the sequences manually or auto generated by hibernate?
when using different schemas don't forget to specify the schema for the sequence otherwise hibernate will use a fallback solution.